# Extending generic classes leads to 'type not assignable' error

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a DAL (Data Access Layer) - DAO (Data Access Object) architecture using TypeScript.
This is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

LIBRARY (Base classes):

IBaseData.ts:

```
// Base data type (actually any object)
export interface IBaseData {
  [x: string]: any;
}
```

BaseDAL.ts:

```
import { IBaseData } from "./IBaseData";
import BaseEntity from "./BaseEntity";

// A utility type that obtains a data type from an entity
type GetDataTypeFromEntity<T extends typeof BaseEntity> =
  T extends typeof BaseEntity<any, infer D extends IBaseData> ? D : never;


// Base abstract DAL class
export default abstract class BaseDAL<
  T extends typeof BaseEntity = typeof BaseEntity
>{

  get entityClass(): T {
    throw new Error("entityClass function must be overridden");
  }

  get resource(): string {
    throw new Error("resource function must be overridden");
  }

  createInstance(data: GetDataTypeFromEntity<T>) {
    return new this.entityClass(this, data);
  }

  wrap<R = InstanceType<T>>(promise: Promise<GetDataTypeFromEntity<T> | GetDataTypeFromEntity<T>[]>) {
    return promise.then((response) =>
      Array.isArray(response)
        ? response.map((obj) => this.createInstance(obj))
        : this.createInstance(response)
    ) as Promise<R>;
  }

  getById<R = InstanceType<T>>(id: string) {
    return this.wrap<R>(this.get(`${this.resource}/${id}`));
  }

  create<R = InstanceType<T>>(data: GetDataTypeFromEntity<T>) {
    return this.wrap<R>(this.post(`${this.resource}`, data));
  }

  get<R = GetDataTypeFromEntity<T>[]>(url: string) {
    return fetch(url) as Promise<R>;
  }

  post<R = GetDataTypeFromEntity<T>>(url: string, data: R) {
    return fetch(url, { body: data as unknown as BodyInit, method: 'POST' }) as Promise<R>;
  }

}
```

BaseEntity.ts:

```
import { IBaseData } from "./IBaseData";
import AbstractDAL from "./AbstractDAL";    

// Base entity class
export default class BaseEntity<
  DAL extends BaseDAL = BaseDAL,
  T extends IBaseData = IBaseData
>{

  private DALInstance: DAL;
  public data: T;

  constructor(DALInstance: DAL, data: T) {
    this.DALInstance = DALInstance;
    this.data = data;
  }

  get DAL(): DAL {
    return this.DALInstance;
  }

  create(): Promise<this> {
    return Promise.reject();

  }
  // Other CRUD commands
}
```

APP (Common classes):

IData.ts:

```
import { IBaseData } from "./IBaseData";

export interface IData extends IBaseData {
  id: string;
}
```

MainDAL.ts:

```
import { IData } from "./IData";
import MainEntity from "./MainEntity";
import BaseDAL from "./BaseDAL";

export default abstract class MainDAL<T extends typeof MainEntity = typeof MainEntity> extends BaseDAL<T>{ // T - Error
  // overrides base getter
  get entityClass() { // Error
    return MainEntity;
  }

  // Additional getter 
  get populate(): string | undefined {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

MainEntity.ts:

```
import { IData } from "./IData";
import BaseEntity from "./BaseEntity";
import MainDAL from "./MainDAL";

export default class MainEntity<DAL extends MainDAL = MainDAL, T extends IData = IData> extends BaseEntity<DAL, T>{ // DAL - Error
  create(): Promise<this> {
    return this.DAL.create(this.data);
  }
}
```

APP (Real classes derived from common ones):

IRole.ts:

```
import { IData } from "./IData";    

export interface IRole extends IData {
  name: string;
}
```

RoleDAL.ts:

```
import Role from "./Role";
import MainDAL from "./MainDAL";

export default class RoleDAL extends MainDAL<typeof Role> { // typeof Role - Error
  get entityClass() { // Error
    return Role;
  }

  // overrides base getter
  get resource() {
    return "role";
  }

  async test() {
    const role: Role = await this.getById('125');
    console.log('Role name', role.data.name);
  }
}
```

Role.ts:

```
import { IRole } from "./IRole";
import RoleDAL from "./RoleDAL";
import MainEntity from "./MainEntity";

class Role extends MainEntity<RoleDAL, IRole>{ // RoleDAL - Error
  async test() {
    const role: Role = await this.DAL.getById('125');
    console.log('Role name', role.data.name);
  }
}
```

The main idea here is the following. There is a library with base classes for further uses.
The abstract class `BaseDAL` has 2 getters that must be overridden in derived classes (`MainDAL` and `RoleDAL`) and several functions for retrieving data. When the user requests data using the `DAL` class, it returns an object (initially it is an instance of BaseEntity) that contains the data, a reference to the `DAL` instance, and `CRUD` functions. Accessing the `DAL` instance is very useful for implementing `CRUD` commands for simple interaction with an object. Then, I import these classes into my app and extend them to suit the real world. This way I end up with generic `MainDAL` and `MainEntity` classes that are parent to real classes like `RoleDAL` and `Role` respectively.

The problems start in the app part when I try to extend the `BaseDAL` & `BaseEntity` classes.
I get the errors `Type 'typeof MainEntity' is not assignable to type 'typeof BaseEntity'` and `Type 'MainDAL<typeof MainEntity>' is not assignable to type 'BaseDAL<typeof BaseEntity>'` respectively. The same issue related to extending the
`MainDAL` & `MainEntity` classes.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/PTAEBkEkCECUEFYE1QApoEMDOBTUBjAG21ywEpQBaam2mgKHpFHlAFcAXAS0K44E9QAgA54OACwwdQAewBGHDFwB2WUBlAATKRpF4AZgCcZAW3XLQOZdwH09oAOI4OAER0AVfqIBixkwFFrPn4AHndLAA8OK001PRl9UExcQJt%20AD5QAF56UFBwnCiYuK8cBKTsHFTgkIxlfgAaUBV9HENQF0jo5VjQGEq3RUyAfg7QAC5QZRwANzaAbkZmZLxtRSFStAx8DjYMQkJBOsF5ACscHbJ6FWjDfW28ftxBjQBvXNAAbQjJrA5DFQAcwAupNjosAL6MJhgFbqOR-QzbaQueDgAjELBYegYBH-ZEYkgVZ5okIfApFHolUTlFbVATZDY0xJ0oK2dLvD6A5yWNn8ADCmKwqDIk3C7zyeQkxgA7lMcHL-IZjIZUAAiKxpQVE-RsZQ7LgyCwmNh-UByPAyObKriaTRWNVkRZ5KFcnmGHBYGRsQz4HAi37-IGgCWS6UyOXTRXKmSqtUer0%20v2gXX67hG0Ams0W2TWgF2h1Oj6uvL4D1SHCQVSKfX%20tYYSZOVweUq%20Uz00LudIUUN5D27QwWKNCcRcLAAOk1wW1WNQEjHTXrRZdjDyMqRwhCsEZVb%20dT9nlEYXS6VQwj8Y5wkwAChfcCEmy9Dzg2wE%20cfQAAfRzOJ%20tvwdsenzAt2IYfH2zg%20hY56mJe44SFYqCoAmwhGrgFBZOk4GSvAyoYPw45jrhSL8MhnqoaoOBXJKNGgKMKFoTg44mBgwhIWcGGZPOE5ljgFa7jWfqoBx1G0XkkzceOvH8dW%207%20gxlGiXkFDYKAt6wfesDpM6oAlqA3IcNA-CQJoW47rJtbPsep62oGALKICPbYf2UEjmO47rqxW6npJBmoAABgAJK8kkJt6vo4BCwDBbaEL%20WQy66auBDltEZlZH0FkHqU1moPWja-i2PgAe%20XZOTRLmDm5E6eZuWlzqOE6oX8AXBaFnrhX6cWLjoCU6XpBnpT%20zaKM%20r6AV2wGnj6hB2UC5WSpVFitBw%20DiKgM0qWo6kmJe3n9clzUcENj5FS%20JVpLlM1zQ5PWKJMsALRBA7Lc4a0bYYhBNK85oyJo-CTPW6hqHqADWygRhYqnQH9xnKHwTQmM44h-ZMADk14APIAMruGjulbWpd44PtxaMK6yyVLyaSEli9BEESrKXR8qLooU3S9CsrOMlzaINOSXTFH0XM6DuIuKPQHKHQCMwVh0aICXJkyszpwhsHIvD4FoOhiosHz4Gh-xsDssaoKziu1srfPa-d%20RPdV47m1leAZU7e61jpUqNeOQMZfWB1uiiaIBvL6K9qAS0O27gk4AHpapf6opExpJPcZk4eRztcEeucOwinrK55MwmMIe0-KwAAqp0BsmCxVL0BTYDwNe15oPypgmBmDNYp6FB0P3DDXNYbT3MmkAvILVLCwMouhrZoCIkCkLQriiIEt3agALJKMorNhJPvTxIk28qB2jJH6AJ-KB2mTs0LvPgMeobMFabT5p65pUwZtyB9T05CiKMCFVIJVSvh2OOoBmDwDtHwQ0yh9j6WcLcUAv9UJq2INEEOi8HJfnYD0HA%20gVA4E0EAxaICLB6ntIQ6YmgDqug3pfHegFuZ3ynlfbmGV2HWwpBzNQ49RYZX4UMA%20agmY1FZk0LsoZpKYKTlne8adSHPVcpJVmUkE4NXckuOh0IoEtzQLAPihBaakC0G0LgcwSFGFMAQDuGYjS9yoAPZxtBGA3BHg8PosAZCEDwKw3oQi3gfHgUjG6gJl70yFKAbxviWGUl6Fwx%20F8Yk4HTr-KcAgZzCntpHFJECX55ltB-OQX8kFtF-mFJMiclER3IaAeMPicBqggdgfg%20ohCeg4IA8OBtqwR0aQ9RpjIMAyiUNIXyzgjImVQGjAAjAAJgAKxo0SqWNCjTxyEBkICGZKSpgYCRmjJoxhfE%20x0OOEJVEdGRKJHs-xW8mHvhSRIrxjSpZ5Fae06ILV7a9LNCcq80ShkZRGWMqOaJxwGSmZoGZCzlmrNsaoDZWydloz2Zco5-TTn1guQcq5ZMIRAA)

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Ugh good luck. I looked at this for a while and I think you're probably going to either have to give up some type safety (just `as any` until it quiets the errors) or refactor significantly (which I don't feel particularly inclined to delve deeply into).

Comment: @jcalz, It is very demotivating to hear it, especially from a TS guru :(

Comment: Maybe if you could reduce your example further I could look into the refactoring, but right now it's just too much for me (at least at the moment).

Comment: @jcalz, Thank you very much for your time and consideration. Please take a look at [this](https://shorturl.at/ozJXZ) code when you have time. I tried to decrease my code as much as possible, but it still looks quite frightening :)

Comment: Comments are (possibly) ephemeral; if you have a [mre] it should be in plaintext in the question.  I’ll look when I get to a real computer in any case

Comment: Oh well I looked again and it's very frustrating. It's like you want [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) but across linked pairs of classes, but that's very hard to do in a type safe way.  Even in your example you have `this.DALInstance.create({ id: '123' })` which doesn't make sense unless `Role` overrides that.  (`{id: '123'}` has no `name` property).  I'm not having fun working on this, so I think I'm going to stop now. Sorry. Good luck!